# Removing a div while scrolling up

Tags: jquery

What I'm trying to do is remove the `<header>` of a page while scrolling. Here's what I have so far - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fnbd/e8z63av1/).

And here's the code:

```
var scrollPoint = $('section').offset().top,
    scrolledPast = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > scrollPoint) {
    scrolledPast = true;
  }

  if ($(window).scrollTop() < scrollPoint && scrolledPast == true) {
    $(window).scrollTop(scrollPoint);
    $('header').remove();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 0);
    scrolledPast = false;
    scrollPoint = 0;
    return false;
  }
});
```

Basically, the visitor can scroll down the page normally and the `<header>` gets removed only when the visitor scrolls back up to the top of the `<section>`.

The only issue I have left is when a visitor is using the scrollbar instead of the mousewheel for scrolling. If he's using the scrollbar, after the `<header>` gets removed, everything goes down, for obvious reasons. Any ideas on solving this?

Comment: I tried your jsFiddle, and the header was removed whether using the mousewheel or manually dragging the scrollbar, I don't think there is any difference. Is that your question?

Comment: Indeed, but the 'Header' is 100% height. After it gets removed you're going 100% down the screen instantly if you're holding the scrollbar. That is my issue currently.

Comment: ahh I see now, would maybe hiding the header instead of removing it help any perhaps? (Edit: I tried, same results)

Answer (score 0):

Like so?

## jsFiddle

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
    var a = $(this).scrollTop(),
        b = $('section').offset().top,
        c = $(this).data('sp');

    if (a >= b) $(this).data('sp', true);
    if (c && a <= b) {
        $('header').remove();
        $(window).scrollTop(0);
    }
})
```

Comment: Still the result is the same as mine - scrolling with scrollbar will result in plummeting down the page after the Header gets dumped. I'm currently trying a overflow:hidden then back to overflow:auto (in an instant succession) just after removing the Header but it doesn't work in IE11 (only Chrome/FF) and that's why I was looking for some kind of a jquery hack.

Comment: ah yeah, I see. I thought I had it working, but it was cause I released the mouse. The problem is when you're still holding pointer down, scroll jumps to where ever your mouse is

Comment: I'm open to any ideas.

Comment: Not really sure there is much you can do apart from making a custom scroll bar. Mousedown will always be lower than scroll bat thus pulling it down. But with a custom div scroll bar, you could better control the events associated and release, or even change por based on mouse position